# Minha function de download corrompendo o arquivo

Tags: php

Eu criei uma function de download mas ela ta corrompendo os arquivos e eu não consigo encontrar o motivo! Baixa normalmente, mas quando eu vou abrir o arquivo ele informa que o arquivo ta em um formato desconhecido ou danificado.

```
public function download($token, $renomear) {
    $local_file = 'download/' . $token . '.zip';
    $download_file = $renomear . '.zip';

    // set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
    $download_rate = 20.5;
    if (file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
        header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $download_file);
        header('Connection: Close');

        flush();
        $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            // send the current file part to the browser
            print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
            // flush the content to the browser
            flush();
            // sleep one second
            sleep(1);
        }
        fclose($file);
    } else {
        $pdo = new PDO\Database();
        $insertStatement = $pdo->insert(array(
                    "item_token" => $token,
                    "valor" => "Erro: o arquivo não existe!"
                ))
                ->into("file_log");
        $insertStatement->execute();
        header("Refresh: 0");
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: conseguiu encontrar o problema?? Testei seu código e teve um comportamento esperado.

Comment: Funciona com alguns e com outros ele até baixa mas quando eu vou abrir aparece um aviso de arquivo corrompido!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possibilidade e utilizar o `readfile`, e alterar Content-Type para `header('Content-Type: application/zip')`;

```
public function download($token, $renomear) {
    $local_file = 'download/' . $token . '.zip';    
    $download_file = $renomear . '.zip';

    $download_rate = 20.5;
    if (file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');      
        header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $download_file);
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
        readfile($local_file);
        exit;

    } else {        
        $pdo = new PDO\Database();
        $insertStatement = $pdo->insert(array(
                    "item_token" => $token,
                    "valor" => "Erro: o arquivo não existe!"
                ))
                ->into("file_log");
        $insertStatement->execute();
        header("Refresh: 0");        
        die();
    }
}
```

[readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Obrigado, aparentemente deu tudo certo agora!

Comment: Você saberia adicionar o $download_rate para limitar a velocidade do download?